# Laravel 7 manual authentication session issue

Tags: php, laravel, session-cookies, laravel-7, php-7.4

**TL;DR:** After succesfull login and redirect to `/home` I got kicked back to `/login` by Controller's middleware (`$this->middleware('auth');`).

I've a [php-apache](https://hub.docker.com/_/php) docker development environment. Finally I'm able to use Laravel 7 for a new service, so I set it up, get the framework and start working with it. I can't use Laravel's hashing algoritm because I've a custom approach that I know can use with `Auth::attempt()` method for [manual authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#authenticating-users).

All set this this point

```php
public function login(Request $r)
{
    $data = $r->validate([
        'username' => 'required|string',
        '_pswrd'   => 'required|string',
    ]);

    $credentials = [
        'login'    => $data['username'],
        'password' => $data['_pswrd'],
        'status'   => 'A',
    ];

    try {
        if (Auth::guard()->attempt($credentials, $r->has('remember'))) {
            // Auth::user() is found and valid so redirect...
            return $r->wantsJson()
                ? new Response('', 204)
                : redirect()->intended('/');
        }

        return back()->with('errors', new MessageBag([ 'auth.failed' ]));

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Log::warning($e);

        return back()->with('errors', new MessageBag([ 'auth.unknown' ]));
    }
}
```

But, then I go to `home` route

```php
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user() === null
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

- Why is Auth::user() null in HomeController?
- Why is my session lost?
- Am I missing some configuration in Apache or laravel's `conf/` folder?

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of problems where the obvious was not checked. Laravel has changed (a lot) User's model and I thought to see it later. `primary_key` and `keyType` attributes must be fixed in order to auth middleware works properly.

I'll leave this answer as I spend a lot of time in this issue always thinking it was related to auth or session configuration when it was not.

Answer (score 0):

What is name the guard? Is it for `web` guard?
So, try to fill the `guard('web')`  or just remove it, directly `Auth::attempt([])`